# How to restore to previous app versions to debug a specific issue?

Tags: git

Say you have a an iOS app that you keep updating every now and then. Apple can show you the traceback for app crashes only if the code hasn't changed.
So I need a way of being able to go to the exact code base when needed.

At the moment I'm thinking of creating a branch for each version and when I need to debug a specific version I just switch to its branch.

1. Is there any downside to the way described above?
2. Is there another standard workflow for this use case?

Comment: You're really looking for tags, not branches. The key difference is that you can't commit to tags, which is fine for your scenario -- you'd be debugging against a specific version, but you wouldn't be fixing the bug in that version, you'd be fixing the bug for your next release.

Comment: @DanielMann I wasn't aware of the concept of tags in git. It definitely is what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I totally agree with this use of tags. I tag the moment I release a new version to the App Store, and I enter that tag number directly into the Organizer in Xcode! That way when a bug arises it is trivial to check out that exact commit.

Comment: @VonC That wasn't intentional my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the comment, you can see an example of such a workflow in "[Git workflow branches strategy](https://medium.com/@stansarr/git-workflow-branches-strategy-4d29f9b2a417)" from [Stan Sarr](https://twitter.com/stan_sarr), using [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), and [creating branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) only when needed:

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/3246/1*5fzIWE84xzQUAcmVMJ4Ouw.png]

> ### Hot-fix:
>
> A hotfix branch is created only if a bug is found in production with the new release by the end users.
> The parent is the `master` branch

```sh
$ git checkout -b hotfix-blocking_bug_from_v0.0.1 master 
//Fix the issue and merge back to master and develop
$ git checkout master
$ git merge hotfix-blocking_bug
$ git push
$ git tag -a v0.0.2 -m "Tag master version 0.0.2 bug fix" master 
$ git push --tags // push the tag to the master// Don’t forget to merge back to develop
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge hotfix-blocking_bug
$ git push
```